# PHP returning sql querystring, not an actual result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

got a slightly odd thing going on, not sure why. I have a PHP script which queries a MySQL DB for some user info.

Here is the offending code:

```
$activities = "SELECT sports FROM userActivityLocation WHERE user = '$userName'";
$result2 = mysql_query($activities);
$sports = mysql_result($result2,0);
```

When the POST goes through (http://www.websiteitshostedon.co.uk/API/getUserActivities.php?user=testtest123), the respons comes:

```
SELECT sports FROM userActivityLocation WHERE user = 'testtest123'Ultimate Volleyball
```

This is clearly not what I'm after, why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an errant echo statement in there?

Comment: there's no way your 3 lines of code would print out ANYTHING, except php warnings/errors. you must have an echo somewhere.

Comment: Right on the money, a few lines below I have n echo statement which is firing out the wrong variable. Sorry to have wasted your time but thank you so much for the insight....is code blindness a thing? I think so!

Comment: Btw, try `prepared statements` to avoid sql injection.

Comment: where is your php code  of `getUserActivities.php`??